# printf parameters affecting each other

Tags: c, double, printf

I have the following code:

```
double dtemp = (some value)
printf("\n***Hand washing: cost per kg/item: %.2f, cost: %.2f.\n", 5, dtemp);
```

It prints out:

> ***Hand washing: cost per kg/item: 0.00, cost: 0.00.

And when I change the constant 5 into a double variable holding 5, it prints (according to the input):

> ***Hand washing: cost per kg/item: 5.00, cost: 20.00.

Why would the constant 5 affect the evaluation of the dtemp? I'm using gcc 4.6.2 (MinGW) and tested it also in TCC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My compiler's (gcc 4.4.3) warning message explains this:

```
   format ‘%.2f’ expects type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

Since you are passing a different type of value (`int`) than specified (`double`) in the format string, the behavior is undefined due to this mismatch

As you observed, once you adjust this to be consistent you get the output you expect. I.e.,

```
/* provide a double value */
printf("\n***Hand washing: cost per kg/item: %.2f, cost: %.2f.\n", 5.0, dtemp);
```

output:

```
***Hand washing: cost per kg/item: 5.00, cost: 3.14.
```

or

```
/* specify an integer value in the format string */
printf("\n***Hand washing: cost per kg/item: %d, cost: %.2f.\n", 5, dtemp);
```

output:

```
***Hand washing: cost per kg/item: 5, cost: 3.14.
```

Always a good idea to crank up the warning levels on the compiler and then follow up on all warnings and make deliberate decisions about what can be ignored and what can't.

Comment: Actually I used '-Wall -ansi -pedantic', but no warning message printed. Is that enough? or there are other switch to rise warning level?

Comment: @Ghasan Oh, ok, great. No, those seem like pretty good switches .. odd, I got this without *any* switches just by default settings.

Answer (score 8):

`f` conversion specifier requires a `double` when used with `printf` functions and your are passing an `int`. Passing an `int` is undefined behavior which means anything can happen.

Comment: So dumping the next value is allowed because it is undefined behavior?

Comment: Yes, undefined behavior is just that, _undefined_. There is no guarantee of what will happen, but it probably isn't what is expected to happen.

Comment: All your program behavior is undefined behavior because of the violation of the requirement you have to pass an `double`.

Answer (score 0):

e  the printf function first parameter is string, it check every %d,then move the point,for example: %d,move 4 len; %lld move 8. 
  int64_t a = 1;int b = 2;
  printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
  the answer is 1,0. because the two %d just get the a lower 4 byte and hight 4 byte.

printf("\n***Hand washing: cost per kg/item: %.2f, cost: %.2f.\n", 5, dtemp); sizeof(doubel) = 8 ,so the printf function just get 0x0000000000000005.

I hope it would help you.