# printf sometimes prints extra garbage

Tags: c, printf

I'm parsing through a `.ppm` file, using `fgetc` to read a single byte at a time, and then converting them to floats by dividing by 255.0 to get colors for use in OpenGL code. This is easy. I print the numbers out for debugging purposes using `printf("%f %f %f\n", color[0], color[1], color[2]);`. Most of the time this works well (see the first line), but occasionally it prints out extra garbage (see the second line).

```
0.086275 0.031373 0.000000
0.133333 0.000000 0.00<BA><B9>9?<D1><D0><D0>=<99><98>^X>3 0.078431 0.000000
```

Any ideas why this might be?

UPDATE:

```
float *read_eight_bit(FILE *file, int rows, int cols)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   float *data = (float *)malloc(rows*cols*3*sizeof(float));                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   int c;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   int i, j, k;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
         for(k = 0; k < 3; k++) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
           if((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
             data[get_index(i, j, k, rows, cols)] = c/255.0f;                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
           }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
           else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
             perror("reached unexpected EOF");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
             free(data);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
             return NULL;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
         }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
   return data;
}
```

This is the actual code that reads things in.

Comment: You're formatting floats as ints. Use printf("%f %f %f\n".... and see what happens.

Comment: Whoops, that's wrong -- the code has `"%f"`. I'll edit the question.

Comment: can you post a snippet of code? How is color defined?

Comment: impossible to help you if you do not post the code snippet in question

Comment: schow us some http://www.sscce.org code

Comment: code snippet will help us understanding ur query...pls post code

Comment: Well, if color[x] isn't of float (or double?) type, undefined behavior is raised. Try to cast them if so.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382694/printf-parameters-affecting-each-other

Comment: is get_index(i, j, k, rows, cols) guaranteed to give a result >= 0 and < (rows * cols * 3) ?

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation I can think of without seeing more code is that the stack is messed up somehow, possibly through a buffer over- or underrun (writing outside an array).

I'd recommend running your code through [cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppcheck/files/latest/download), as it can detect many of these sorts of problems.